# C's equivalent to Python's "or" in assignment

Tags: c

In Python you are able to assign values with the "or" operator.

`two = 2 or None`

In the above expression, `two` will become equal to `2`.

Can C replicate this? I doubt `int two = 2 || NULL;` would work, but is there a solution other than an if statement?

Comment: not without an  `if`  or a ternary. In c the `||`  and `&&`  operators only return 0 or 1

Comment: `NULL` in C represents an unassigned pointer value.

Comment: what exactly is the point of such an assignment?

Comment: What's wrong with an if-statement? It's not that the CPU can magically avoid checking a condition before selecting one of two options.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `a or b` works like this:

1. If `bool(a) == True`, return `a`
2. If, then, `bool(b) == True`, return `b`
3. Otherwise, return the last operand, namely, `b`

So, this is a simple ternary operator: `(a)? (a) : (b);`

---

Let's take a look at how Python's *logical OR* operator works internally:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('5 or None')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              3 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP      9
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
        >>    9 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, the `or` is actually `JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP`, which is implemented [in the CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/25e4f779d7ae9f37a1933cb5cbfad06e673c01f9/Python/ceval.c#L2939), line #2939.

`JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP(target)` works like this:

1. If the Top Of the Stack (TOS) is truthy (that is, either it's equal to `Py_True`, or `PyObject_IsTrue(TOS)` is greater than zero), set the bytecode counter to `target`. TOS is popped
2. Otherwise, continue execution

It turns out that, as expected, the result is determined with a bunch of `if` statements.

Comment: `/* Where a is only evaluated once */` GCC provides `(a) ?: (b)` as an extension for this use.

Comment: @Deduplicator where is that a requirement?

Comment: @Kevin: The goal was finding a C equivalent to the Python expression...

Comment: @Deduplicator, a comment inside a comment... nice! Well, Python's `or` short-circuits, right, just like C's. But C doesn't have any 'special' short-circuiting `or` that always returns one of its operands, as far as I know.

Comment: Well, it can be emulated by `(x = a) ? x : b`

Comment: The line number in the VCS web page used to be both an anchor and a link, not sure if it's still like that.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Option 1
int two;
if(2) {
two = 2;
} else {
two = 0;
}

// Option 2
int two = 2 ? 2 : 0;
```

Comment: `if`-statement detected: fail